# MutationObserver reports no changes in framset within asp page

Tags: javascript, opera, frames, userscripts, mutation-observers

I'm trying to write a userscript on Opera using Tampermonkey (although I tried ViolentMonkey already with the same results) that will run on my router's config page and calculate some values based on the statistics displayed.

The problem is, it is an .asp page, with only a `frameset` (no body element, although I have no idea if this is normal for asp or not, never used it) and 3 `frame` elements within it. After trying some DOM methods, which work but require some very inelegant approaches to actually detecting what's on the page since the url doesn't change, I stumbled upon `MutationObserver` which kicks ass, but I can't seem to get it to return any events, no matter what I do.

The `MutationObserver` works when I try it on `google.com` and reports normally. My code so far is just this test for `MutationObserver` functionality, so it's pretty much a copy/paste from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Example_usage) and looks like this (slightly modified):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       meh
// @match      http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/index.asp
// @run-at     document-end
// ==/UserScript==

// MDN code starts here
var target = document.body;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});

var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true };

observer.observe(target, config);
// end of userscript
```

This exact code works perfectly fine on `google.com`. Also my `@match` directive isn't the problem since I log the observer to the console (not shown here) to make sure it matches the proper url.

I've tried various elements as targets (in case that was the problem) such as `window.frames['framename'].document.body` and the like, and I've tried with and without `subtree` in the configuration, as well as using `document-start` for the `@run-at` directive. No matter what, I get no mutations logged into the console.

I haven't been able to find anything online concerning this particular case so I need to ask, is there anything special about .asp pages that can mess with `MutationObserver` or is this something to do with `frame`s and `frameset`s?

edit - quite ironically, the only place online I could find to test my code other than the router's interface is [The World's Worst Website](http://www.angelfire.com/super/badwebs/). Not even jsfiddle and codepen will put up with `frameset` and `frame`.

Comment: This is a Frame thing (and possibly Opera).  Don't set the script to run on the frameset URL. Set it to run in the target frame URL(s). EG: `http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/port-forwarding.asp` or whatever.

Comment: I tried that, but still nothing. After making some tests on the "worst website" and its frame-hell siblings, it seems to me that the problem isn't so much with frames or my targeting, but more with the fact that when frames are loaded, no DOM event is fired. Still testing.

Comment: No, DOM events are fired.  You're doing something else or Opera does not behave in the standard way in regards to userscripts and (i)frames (Doubtful, but there may be a setting you need to set).

Comment: You might be right that it's Opera. Going to test on Chrome and Firefox now. In the case of [this](http://users.ipa.net/~djhill/frmain.html) page, if I target the inner frame with the observer and remove something within its `body` I get an event. If I run at the containing page scope, while removing the element with a timeout (otherwise the inner page doesn't have time to load, even with `document-end`) no event fires. It seems to be some sort of sandboxing for events, even though this is the same domain.

Comment: Chrome behaves in the exact same way, as expected considering the common layout engine.

Comment: Firefox behaves in the same way as well, it seems this is a frames thing, not a peculiar browser behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to put this to rest. I originally wanted to approach my problem this way in order to avoid using the greasemonkey api to store values (because if I'm within a frame's context and I refresh, stored variables are wiped) and to use a more elegant and simple way of checking whether a specific frame is loaded with a specific url. Turns out browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera) will not spawn an event when a new url is loaded within a `frame` (I don't know if for `iframes` the behavior is the same, due to sandboxing, or `iframes` behave differently than ancient `frames`).

All in all, if you need to do something like this (maintain a variable in a userscript between refreshes of a frame), target the frame you specifically want to monitor with the `@match` directive and use the greasemonkey api (or whatever api your userscript extension has for storing values permanently). If you want to do this on a website you're making yourself, *don't use frames* (preferrably), or use `postMesssage` or attach event handlers where you need them.

The gist is, frames are terrible.